# Which authentication method is a better solution ? restful or authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a Rails 3 web application and i wanna choose between restful authentication and authlogic method. 
Among restful authentication and Authlogic, which one is better, based on the foolproof security , customisable and hackproof ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise), especially with a Rails 3 application.

Answer (score 0):

restfull_authentification is anymore Rails 3 compatible and not really maintain. So I advice you to use authlogic if you want choose between this 2 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, restful authentication is no longer being maintained.  I'd suggest authlogic as it also packs several options to expand (OAuth, etc), or check our Devise.